# HTTP Response Stream to file in c#

Tags: c#

I want to write my http response to a file but my file is always empty. Why?

```
using (Stream outputfile = File.OpenWrite(objecttype + ".txt"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = context.Response.OutputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        outputfile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    outputfile.Flush();
    outputfile.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where did you put that code? If you're **writing** into response stream then current position is always at the **end of the response stream** (nothing to read).

Comment: I think `Response.OutputStream` is what you send back to a client. So you are supposed to write to this stream rather than read it.

Comment: Please be some eloborative.As if the code is executed.It will sure that it will write data into the file.If the response from http contains data.And dont put **ouputfile.Flush()** outside the loop.Because **outputFile.Flush()** is used for saving the file time to time but not actually closing it.Then after complete writing you can put **outputFile.Close()** outside the loop.To close the file and release the file handle.

Comment: The code is written after the response stream is populated. I have tried to put position=0 before this code but no effect.

Comment: Is response stream seekable?

Comment: I have put some logging to find the error. The error is on context.Response.OutputStream.Read saying "Specified method is not supported" (System.NotSupportedException). How can I resolve this?